# FxCop custom rule for nested If

Tags: .net, fxcop, ndepend

I am trying to get following metrics report for .Net assemblies
1. Boolean expression
2. Nested If
3. Method Parameters 
3. Nested try
4. Missing switch default
5. Class fan-out complexity

Basically, I want to generate toxicity report for these complexities. I see that Sonar could generate same for java applications. But I don't see anything available with .Net using FxCop or nDepend. I tried creating custom rules, but not able to get it done with any of tool.
Is it possible to create custom rules with FxCop and get analysis report, and then create complexity measure from it?
I have generated nested try rule with FxCop. But nested If seems difficult, because IL generate lot of goto statements which makes difficult to identify if "If" statements are nested or parallel placed. Same with Boolean complexity because of stack push-pop operations.

I think sonar make use of checkstyle for java to generate these reports. Is it source code based analyser? or also works with IL? Do I need to work with styleCop to get it worked?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen that NDepend supports the code metric [IL Nesting Depth](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#ILNestingDepth). While it doesn't distinguishes between causes of the depth (if, goto, switch/case, loop...) it is computed from the IL and is pretty accurate in most situations.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have seen this. As you mentioned it does not distinguish statements. I tried writing custom query, but unable to find anything which will give depth of specific conditions. We are trying to create same toxicity report which is available for Java using Sonar for .Net applications.